# Scaled svg path on hover is not centered

Tags: css, svg, scale, css-transforms

I have an svg `<path>` that I want scaled on mouse hover. The scaled path should be centered on top of its original location. I have read other similar posts but could not get it done.

I tried using `transform-origin: 50% 50%;`, `transform-origin: 0 0;`, and `transform-origin: center;` and also tried removing `transform-origin` all throughout, but none of them works as intended since the scaled path has an offset of several pixels:

```css
path {
  fill: #f00
}

path:hover {
  fill: #000;
  transform: scale(2);
  -ms-transform: scale(2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 881 571" pointer-events="fill" fill="none" fill-opacity="1">
        <path d="M447 263h1-1 1v-1 1h1-1 1-1 1v1h1-1 2v1h1v1h-1 1-1v1h1v1h1-1v1h-1v1-1 1h-1v1h-1v3h-1v-1h-2v-1h-1v-1h-2v-2h-1v-3h-1v-1h1-1 1v-1h1v-2h1-1v1-2 1h1v1h1v-1h1v1h1z"/>
      </svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG artbox seems enormous, and I believe this is part of the issue. I tried cleaning it up a bit to fit the content of the SVG, and I wrapped the element inside of a `div`.

Here's the SVG with a more proportionate artbox:

```css
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div {
  fill: #f00;
  width:127px;
  height:150px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

div:hover {
  fill: #000;
  transform: scale(2);
  -ms-transform: scale(2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M65.5 23.583h10.583H65.5h10.583V13v10.583h10.584-10.584 10.584-10.584 10.584v10.584H97.25 86.667h21.166V44.75h10.584v10.583h-10.584 10.584-10.584v10.584h10.584V76.5H129h-10.583v10.583h-10.584v10.584-10.584 10.584H97.25v10.583H86.667V140H76.083v-10.583H54.917v-10.584H44.333V108.25H23.167V87.083H12.583v-31.75H2V44.75h10.583H2h10.583V34.167h10.584V13H33.75 23.167v10.583V2.417 13H33.75v10.583h10.583V13h10.584v10.583H65.5z"/>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Hope it helps!